# How to find all controls inside iframe asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

How to find all controls id and text inside .aspx page and iframe asp.net

for e.g

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control control, string id)
{
    if (control == null) return null;
     //try to find the control at the current level
    Control ctrl = control.FindControl(id);

    if (ctrl == null)
    {
        //search the children
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            ctrl = FindControlRecursive(child, id);

            if (ctrl != null) break;
        }
    }
    return ctrl;
}
```

above method helping by giving id ....
i need to find both .aspx and iframe controls id and text .....

how can i get it...
thanks.....